# Package name issue

Tags: android, package, admob, ads

My package name has been blocked due to some reason and that's why the ads are not showing.
Can someone help me that how to unblock the package name? or else anyone please provide the support email to contact admob support team.

I have integrated admob ads in my application and i am expecting to show it in my app

Answer (score 0):

you should use test application and test ad id while doing test, please follow  the follow link

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

or u can get some help while communicate with google admob team by follow link

https://support.google.com/admob/gethelp

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
As i am already using test ad id. It won't works. I mean test ad also not showing. But when i changed the package name of the app. All ads are working fine.

Also i already tried to contact support team using your given above link. It won't allow to send an email at the end after following all the steps. Just an option to ask community.

Comment: Any update for me?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).